# logout via Spring 3 Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

No matter what I do I cannot get logout to work.  I have a menu that is only visable via members role.  I have tried both invalidate of the session, as well as the /j_spring_security_logout via the Spring documentation...  Both forward to the home page, but the menu and credentials appear on the home page.  Thus the logout does not work.  Here is my Spring Security.xml file entries.

```
<logout logout-url="/logout"/>
<logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/home" 
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"  invalidate-session="true"/>
```

As you can see I have tried both.   Here is the logout controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    logger.info("Logging out!");

    response.setHeader("pragma", "no-cache");              
    response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");

    Cookie jSessionCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", null);
    jSessionCookie.setMaxAge(0);
    response.addCookie(jSessionCookie);
    Cookie activityIdCookie = new Cookie("activityId", null);
    activityIdCookie.setMaxAge(0);
    response.addCookie(activityIdCookie);  

    request.getSession().invalidate(); //Attempt to logout user.    

    return ("redirect://");
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Logout* is handled by security filter chain (just like almost everything in Spring Security). The actual *logout* request will never make it to dispatcher servlet. Don't implement logout logic  manually (session invalidation, etc.). See *Ralph's* answer...

Answer (score 1):

You only need one logout handler and NO additional controller:

```
<logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/home" />
```

Just let the user request the url `http://localhost/yourApp/logout`.

Comment: I did that..  It takes me to the Home page..  The problem is the user is still loged in.  Their permissions are still there, the user credentitals are still present.

Comment: That is the way to go, if it does not work, the problem must be somewhere else. Do you use tomcat? The tomcat manager has a feature to look at the session. Spring Security store its user information in the session. You can use the tomact manager to verify that the session id changes on logout and have a look at the information stored by spring security.

Comment: JBoss 7.1..  I am using Spring 3.1.4.

Comment: Do you use Spring Form Based login, or some Server Functionality for login?

Comment: <beans:bean id="simpleUserDetailsServive" class="com.newweighprogram.security.SimpleUserDetailsService">
</beans:bean>
 
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider user-service-ref='simpleUserDetailsServive'/>
 </authentication-manager>

Comment: SimpleUserDetailService extends Spring's UserDetailsService